# Fortran 90 - Compute extremely large values

Tags: fortran, precision, fortran90

I am currently learning Fortran 90 and have been experimenting with the `kind` and `selected_real_kind` parameters for variables. In my experimentation, I have found out that variables can only contain values up to 33 digits long. My question is, how can I calculate longer numbers? For example, how can I calculate a 40-digit number, if that is even possible? Please provide source code.

As a side note, I have noticed that python and common lisp can calculate numbers with hundreds of digits without losing precision. Does such capability exist in Fortran, and if not, can it be emulated?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to compute with extremely long numbers you need a library, such as [ARPREC](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/). Otherwise the highest native ranks are processor dependent and , e.g., for `gfortran` it is 128-bit (kind 16) on most platforms. You could also try C libraries sach as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: Though gfortran requires an arbitrary precision library now (http://www.mpfr.org/), thus it might be possible to support higher precisions with gfortran theoretically, though I am not quite sure about it. Some more pointers can also be found at: http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/

Comment: I think such an arbitrary length implementation would not be standard Fortran. There would be problems with sequence association.  Such data could effectively be only alloatables or pointers.

Comment: I downloaded ARPREC and mpdist, yet I don't see how to call them from my program. On Geany, compiling with gFortran, it gives the error that it "cannot find mpdist.mod", even though I have set it in $PATH. I'm on Linux Mint 13, if that helps.

Comment: gfortran does not look in $PATH AFAIK. You shoul set the module paths using -I and -J options.